# Using delayed_job to queue a method from a gem in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I would like to queue the method [upload_to_scribd](https://github.com/ProtectedMethod/scribd_fu/blob/master/lib/scribd_fu.rb#L188) (from the gem [scribd_fu](https://github.com/ProtectedMethod/scribd_fu)) using delayed_job.

Is there any way I can do this without modifying the gem itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything special to get this to work. For example, you can do probably do something like this:

```
ScribdFu.new.delay.upload_to_scribd
```

If you want you can also wrap this in a function or model of your own:

```
class Attachment
  def upload
    ScribdFu.new(self).upload_to_scribd
  end
end

Attachment.first.delay.upload
```

P.S: I don't know if my syntax for the calls to the ScribdFu gem are correct, but you should be able to use the delay method in this way to queue the delayed job.

To accomplish what you want in your comment, create a file called (config/initializers/delay_scribd.rb) and add the following to it:

```
module ScribdFu
  module InstanceMethod
    handle_asynchronously :upload_to_scribd
  end
end
```

This will mean that any time this function is called it will be called in a delayed job, without having to explicitly call delay on the method.
end

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like every call to upload_to_scribd to be handled by delayed_job, rather than making an explicit call. The reason for this is that the gem adds an after_save method which calls :upload_to_scribd, and it is this in particular which I want to delay. Could I simply explicitly set after_save :upload in conjunction with the method from your answer? Would this override the default after_save from ScribdFu? If not, how can I override this? If it was not overridden, upload_to_scribd would be called twice - once by the gem and once via the explicit upload method.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution for modifying the default behavior as well.